# How to get this HTML table's text box value using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried different approaches, but I'm missing something crucial:

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santosonit/wpkog0z4/14/#&togetherjs=kiKDnBLMz1) version

```
function saveData() {
  var table = document.getElementById("dtable");

  var [, ...tr] = table.querySelectorAll("tr");
  var tableData = [...tr].map(r => {
    var td = r.querySelectorAll("td");
    return [...td].map((c, j) => j < 6 ? c.innerHTML : j == 6 ? c.querySelectorAll("select")[0].value : j == 7 ? c.querySelectorAll('comments')[0].value);
  })
  tableData = tableData.filter(e => e[6] != 'empty');

}
```

Note for column counting purpose: The first column of the table is hidden.

This is the column whose data is to be grabbed:

```
<td><input type="text" name="comments" style="width:99%;"></td>
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Could you provide a little example of how HTML looks like?

Comment: I also recommend that you make a JS Fiddle jsfiddle.net or use Stackoverflow's version of that.

Comment: Would be nice if you post an answer to your own question. It may help other developers to solve their issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution, which was given by a good soul on Fiddle:

```
function saveData() {
  var table = document.getElementById("dtable");

  var [, ...tr] = table.querySelectorAll("tr");
  var tableData = [...tr].map(r => {
    var td = r.querySelectorAll("td");
    return [...td].map((c, j) => j < 6 ? c.innerHTML : j == 6 ? c.querySelectorAll("select")[0].value : j == 7 ? c.querySelectorAll('input[name="comments"]')[0].value : '')})
  tableData = tableData.filter(e => e[6] != 'empty');
}
```

and this is what's changed:

**From:**

```
c.querySelectorAll('comments')[0].value
```

**To**

```
c.querySelectorAll('input[name="comments"]')[0].value
```

Not sure why he/she wouldn't post the answer himself/herself.

Comment: Please specify exactly what is different. :)